# Java getting nullpointerexception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

mainMethod.java

```
public class mainMethod{
    public animalsData[] animals;

    public mainMethod(){
        animals[this.animals.length + 1] = new animalsData("CAT", "4");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainMethod run = new mainMethod();
    }
}
```

animalsData.java

```
public class animalsData{
    String name, l;

    public animalsData(String name, String l) {
        super();
        this.name= name;
        this.l= l;
    }
}
```

I hava this problem: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: `animals` has not been assigned a value. Now that you know what the problem is, please delete and/or help me close this question. (P.S. there are many such related questions. Try searching first for "ideas" about what could be wrong.)

Comment: Where do you initialize `animals`?

Comment: this.animals is `null` so it's not possible to acces length property

Comment: Also, in addition, `arr[arr.length + 1]` is *never* valid in Java because arrays have a *fixed length*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are never initializing your `animals` array in your `mainMethod` class.

In your `public mainMethod()` method, you need to do `animals = new animalsData[INITIAL SIZE];`

If you want it to grow automatically, you should use a `List`. Even then you would not use `this.animals.length + 1` as its index. you would simply do `List.add()`

Comment: it's an array not an object, actually, so he's going about it totally wrong. :-/

Comment: @Gray - per the spec, yes. But the OP is obviously new to the language and since you instantiate arrays and objects in different fashions (`new Object()` versus `new int[5]`), it's best to stay simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
public List<animalsData> animals = new ArrayList<animalsData>()

public mainMethod(){
    animals.add(new animalsData("CAT", "4"));
}
```

learn more about Lists in Java, arrays are not expandable by default. And can not expand beyond it's dimension if you add an item after last item of the array.

Comment: It is good that you provide an alternate solution, but you should mention what is actually causing the errors he is encountering.

Comment: I've seen another answers explaining this, why to reinvent the wheel? :)

Answer (score 1):

**1.** `Array` **must be initialized** when its `declared`.

**Eg:**

```
public animalsData[] animals; 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainMethod run = new mainMethod();
        System.out.println(run.animals.length);
    }
```

The above code gives a `NullPointerException`, cause `animals` which is an `Object Reference Array Variable` is **Null** and is **not assigned** the `Array Object` on the heap.

```
public animalsData[] animals = new animalsData[10]; 


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            mainMethod run = new mainMethod();
            System.out.println(run.animals.length);
        }
```

**The above code works fine....as the Array is now initialized.**

I would recommend you to use `java.util.Collections` instead of arrays, they are very flexible.

`List<animalsData> animals = new ArrayList<animalsData>();`